# How to have the system run a bash script to remap keys after login?

Tags: bash, scripts, init.d, init

I've got a `setup-notebook-keyboard.sh` script that I run everytime after logging in because I like my keyboard with the

- <kbd>CapsLock</kbd> -> <kbd>Esc</kbd>,
- <kbd>CapsLock</kbd>+Key -> <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+Key

setting.

I've tried to set this up before, but wasn't able to.
I think I've tried setting it up in `init.d` and also with ubuntu "run on startup". I guess both cases didn't work because they are not run on a shell environment or something...

But anyway, I got stuck with running the script every time after startup and after closing the lid of the Notebook. Can somebody help?

Edit: I don't think this is a duplicate of 'how to persistently remap keys in Ubuntu', I have a script which does two things and I'm happy with it since I've been using it since last year, I just wasn't able to get it to run automatically and I have researched and tried it in different ways.

**Edit 2:** Please remove the duplicate tag. I've tried the suggestion on the question and none of them worked. I've now tried just adding a simple `echo "(profanity) (location)" >> ~/file` in:

- `~/.profile`
- `~/.xinitrc`
- `~/.xsession`
- `~/.gnomerc`

The machine is just not doing nothing on the files, or I've done something very wrong.

I've tried adding a `(profanity).desktop` entry in `~/.config/autostart`, tried using the full paths, tried `/etc/X11/Xsession.d/00_xx` file, tried `00` and `100`, closing the lid and opening, rebooting, etc.

I test it by checking if the CapsLock key lights up or not when I press it, because after I execute `setup-notebook-keyboard.sh` it doesn't light up anymore.

Aditional info that may be important: I'm using gnome shell and it's a graphic user interface.

Version:
`10:37:34 ~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.4 LTS
Release:    16.04
Codename:   xenial`

**Ps.:** Now I tried adding `echo "(profanity)" >> file` on `~/.bashrc`, it runs when I open a terminal(and sorry in advance if you thought I was running ubuntu on a terminal in the first place). So... Why is it so hard to just have a script execute after I log in? No wonder I gave up on it 1 year ago x(

Comment: "didn't work because they are not run on a shell environment or something." ? Try `cron`'s `@reboot` or read `man pm-action`

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! I’m convinced that [Oli’s answer](/a/749662/175814) and [Stuarts’s answer](/a/802493/175814) are perfectly fine to run arbitrary programs/scripts like yours at X.org session start-up. Did you read and try them? If so, why are you dissatisfied with them? (I’m voting to keep your question closed as a duplicate until you give us a convincing rationale against the current duplicate status.)

Comment: Will try both suggestions and get back to you

Answer (score 1):

Add a command to run this script in ~/.profile file. It’ll run as user every time you log in.

If you want to execute some command every time you open new tty(for example every time you open new terminal) you can add command to ~/.bashrc file.

Comment: so, I open my ~/.profile and there it is a `setup-notebook-keyboard.sh` line at the end of it, for some reason this is there since last year when I tried setting this up and gave up... The script consists of a `setxkbmap` and a `xcape` command, wondering if it could be that some service or daemon isn't up yet when it tries to run it? But anyway, not working for me..

Comment: Check if your script has na execute permission (chmod+x) and try passing absolute path to that script.

Comment: You can also try adding ‚hohup’ before command and & after it (it pushes command to the background)

Comment: script is +x: `-rwxr-xr-x 1 buzaga buzaga   78 Dez 17  2017 setup-notebook-keyboard.sh`, tried it with full path, verified full path is written correctly. Closed and opened lid, logged in, did not work, added nohup before and after, did not work...

Comment: When you close the lid, you do not log out - just freezes the session.